# Dispatching an action after Store state change in ReactJS (with Alt)

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

My application is a simple file explorer, and has three components:

- A Tree: representing a directory tree created by user;
- A Simple page: with the selected directory content;
- A Notification Component: to handle messages triggered by user actions.

When the user creates a new folder, the file store (containing all data related to both components) is updated with the server response and notifies the components, with is working fine.

But I need to trigger an Action that will add a message with the result to NotificationStore. This should be an easy task, but I'm trying to do this for a long time, with no success.

The closer I got to solve was creating a "store.listen()" inside the componentDidMount() and then calling my Action (adding the notification message), which was successfully triggered. But it result in an error: "Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch".

Is there any way to call an action after store state change?

Update:

An alternative could be binding the NotificationStore with FileActions and then use the "waitFor(FileStore.dispatchToken)" and THEN set the message in the Store. It could work in this case, but maybe not in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store that need to listen to NotificationStore action, add an listener:

```
     this.bindListeners({
        onActionSomething: NotificationAction.sendNotifcation
    });
```

this will take trigger function in this store called onActionSomething after action sendNotifcation in NotificationActions.

Do not forget to waitFor the dispatcher from other Notification:

```
onActionSomething(data) {
        this.waitFor(NotificationStore);
        this.pages = data;
    }
```

Data parameter will be the same as in Notification one